# Cloudy transparent edge to div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a "cloudy transparent edge" to a bootstrap modal. Is this possible?

I have tried this CSS:

```
  .modal-content {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:
            5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(243, 156, 18, 0.1) inset,
            -5px -5px 10px 0 rgba(243, 156, 18, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:
            5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(243, 156, 18, 0.1) inset,
            -5px -5px 10px 0 rgba(243, 156, 18, 0.1) inset;
    -o-box-shadow:
            5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(243, 156, 18, 0.1) inset,
            -5px -5px 10px 0 rgba(243, 156, 18, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow:
            5px 5px 10px 0 rgba(243, 156, 18, 0.1) inset,
            -5px -5px 10px 0 rgba(243, 156, 18, 0.1) inset;
  }
```

The effect I want looks lie the photo below, with the blurring to transparent and I want it over 5px all along the square border of the div/bootstrap.

My CSS achieves this for a color but I tried RGBA with opacity and it does not work

[image]

Comment: What is a "cloudy transparent edge"? Where is the HTML? What are you applying this to?

Comment: I want the same effect as a blurred edge in photoshop, where the blurring gives way to the background layer.

Comment: Any Screenshot of image you want to achieve ?

Comment: Hi @ Swapna I have updated question. thanks

Comment: If you have PSD file , On this layer of image , Right clicking on it , provides an option to copy CSS of this . Try that option once . It may provide you with the same.

Comment: You might be able to get away with using masks if you're willing to abandon internet explorer and edge users. E.g. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvJRxY But IE and edge don't support masks so it isn't the best solution (which is why I'm posting it as a comment and not an answer)